# Removing the yellow bar in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I am a new user to Visual Studio and when I code I notice a line in the left side, what is it called and is there any way to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the changes tracker. You can disable it in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> uncheck "Track changes"

[image: Visual Studio Options]